# How to calculate the maximum of a two dimensional function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given the function $f(x,y) = \begin {cases} \frac{6}{7}(x^2 + \frac{xy}{2})&\text{ , } (x,y) \in (0,1)\times(0,2)\\ 0&\text{ , } (x,y) \notin (0,1)\times(0,2) \end{cases} $

I have tried finding the point where the tangent plane is parallel to the axis plane. Solving the $\begin {cases} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(x,y) = 0 \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(x,y) = 0\end {cases}$ equation system gave me the result is the $(0, 0)$ point. I got the same result checking where the $\nabla f = \vec{0}$. However using the "D-test", which I found on the internet, showed that it is actually a minimum point of the function. The problem is that the maximum point is not in a point where the tangent plane is parallel to the axis plane, rather at the edge of this $(0,1)\times(0,2)$ area. I know by checking the plot of the function that this maximum point is in $(1, 2)$, however I would like to know how could I possibly calculate it by myself.

Comment: In general, to find an optimum in a connected region, you check for optima in the interior by finding critical points (set the gradient equal to zero), and then check for optima on the boundary. For the boundary, you can sometimes use the method of Lagrange multipliers, but in this case it is simple to check each side of your rectangle for optima. Note that however since your region is defined by open intervals, there will be no maximum; as $(x,y)$ approaches $(1,2)$, the value of the function will increase arbitrarily close to the "maximum value," but never attain it.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, I have noticed that the maximum is $\lim_{x\to1}\lim_{y\to2} f(x,y)$. You say in this particular case I can simple check the boundaries of this rectangle. That means I have to calculate 4 different "functions"? Like one side of the rectangle when for example $x=0$, and $y \in (0, 1)$, getting a function with a single variable and calculating its derivate and so on like the normal maximum finding with single variable functions, right? Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm sorry but the reason why I'm being so particular is that I feel really passionate about understanding these things:)

Comment: Yes, that's right: consider the restriction of $f$ to each of the four sides to get a single-variable function, and maximize each.